Intermittent High Latency in Flink
I am working with an Apache Flink application that reads data streams from Kafka. The application processes the streams, creating objects from the data and calculating the processing time by marking the start time at object creation and the end time after performing a series of transformations including keyBy and some calculations.
In most cases, the processing times recorded are between 0-1 ms. However, I've noticed that some results show an unusually high processing time of over 10 ms. This behavior seems to be intermittent and varies between runs, despite the following consistent setup:

The Flink cluster is deployed in standalone mode.
I restart the cluster before each run to ensure a consistent environment.
The same JAR file is used for all the runs.

What could be causing these intermittent spikes in processing time? How can I diagnose the underlying issue? Or is this fluctuation normal?

That sort of variation in latency isn't surprising.
First thing that comes to mind is garbage collection. If you haven't already done so, it might help to use the latest Flink release with Java 17 or 21, with ZGC.
There are many other configuration details that could play a factor too. Without knowing a lot more about your application and environment it's hard to know where to start.

Thank you for your response. I have another question regarding measuring processing times on a cluster with multiple task managers. Must I only use System.currentTimeMillis() to obtain timestamps, rather than System.nanoTime(), given that in a multi-machine environment, even with synchronized clocks, the time sources for System.nanoTime() are different? However, if the computations are not complex, using System.currentTimeMillis() might result in a 0 ms time difference. Is there a solution to this issue?

NTP can only achieve about 1ms accuracy with machines on the same LAN, and it gets worse from there. Unless you are able to build a custom cluster, I don't think there's a way to do this other than by running everything on a single machine.
